# Convert and format data in a web tile

Tags: microsoft-band

I want to create a web tile for Microsoft Band to display JSON data received from a web service. However the service returns data in very raw format, is it possible to format them before they are displayed on the Band? Or the only options is to display the data as it is returned by the service?

For example timestamps are returned as Numbers which I want to convert to human readable dates and times; or to concatenate strings from multiple JSON property.

Thank you.

György

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion of data is not possible. If you need to process the JSON then you need to build that into your endpoint's JSON data (or create an endpoint that handles the conversion).